# Create DataFrame columns dynamically from meta data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to Python and Databricks.

I have data in the text file without column headers.

'|' is the column value delimiter in this text file

I do have the details about the column names and their order in a separate excel file.

**I have to create DataFrame with columns details which I do have then I have to import the data rows in it**

***Please suggest the best way to create DataFrame columns where should I maintain this columns details (Names, Type, Order)***

Sample data in the text file:-

```
C1|CL1|23|dsfr|54|hjhg|nnf|hb
C1|CL2|23|dsfe|344|er|nnf||fg
C1|CL3|23|dsef|364|e|nnf|fg
C2|CL1a|2783|d56sfr|54|hjhg|nbvc|hb
C2|CL2a|253|dsf56e|344|er|hjhgf||fyyg
C2|CL3a|2673|dse56f|364|e|tre|ttt|yy
```

Header Details:-

```
Col1(string)
Col2(string)
Col3(number)
..
..
```

Please note that in reality, I do have more than 300 columns with string, number, DateTime, bool types

Comment: you should provide sample data row and excel file too.

Comment: Where should I store the column header details before creating the Data Frame columns

Comment: are you using databricks, you reading the file via pandas or Pyspark? as Dishin said can you post the raw details of your header, in PySpark can you pass in the Schema before you declare your dataframe.

Comment: I am using Azure Databricks. My data file with no columns header will be coming in Azure storage. I have created one Azure data factory piple to invoke my notebook. I have to understand within notebook while creating dataframe

Comment: 1. Where should I maintain columns header meta data details? Should I store this information in JSON FORMAT.
2. If yes, how can use JSON to create columns for dataframe

Answer (score 1):

`headers_df = pd.read_csv('path to headers csv')
headers = headers_df.values.tolist()`

## Assign columns name

`pd.read_csv('path/to/file/without_header.csv',sep='|',names=headers)`

hope this answer your question

Comment: Where will I maintain column type details

Comment: @Varun05 You do not need to maintain column type details pandas do itself by the data inside the columns